# Add blown in insulation by hand

Tags: insulation, attic

I have a few small areas in my attic that don't have sufficient insulation. The insulation already in place is blown-in. How practical is it to fluff up blow-in insulation and deposit it by hand in the areas of interest?

A thermal/infrared camera reveals that I have cold areas in the corners where the exterior wall meets the ceiling. So, I'm thinking I could use a garden rake to push the insulation just a bit closer to the soffit to cover that area, but, of course, leave room for air flow.

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18420/can-i-install-cellulose-insulation-without-a-blower-machine/35687#35687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you want to do. If you are using fiberglass, be sure to wear gloves and other protection, and take a shower when you are done.

Comment: …And long sleeves. Fiberglass is awful to work with, and is really irritating to the skin. You don't want to be picking glass fibers out of your flesh for days. I hate the stuff, personally. Go with cellulose if you can, IMHO.

Comment: ...and wear a respirator.

Comment: Fiberglass blown in really, really sucks!! Cellulose is so much easier to use as Dirt says.